# Function reference and "inline" function declaration

Tags: javascript

I have a scenario where I can pass a function or have it declared already. Since the function itself is not going to be used anywhere else I was planning to use an anonymous function instead, but the thing it's not working, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

**As it is right now:**

```
function connectStatic(connect, dir) {
  return connect.static(require('path').resolve(dir));
}

// ...
middleware: function (connect) {
  return [proxySnippet, connectStatic(connect, './')];
}
// ...
```

**As I would like it to be:**

```
// ...
middleware: function (connect) {
  return [proxySnippet, function () {
    return connect.static(require('path').resolve('./'));
  }];
// ...
```

Anyway, if I do:

```
// ...
middleware: function (connect) {
  return [proxySnippet, connect.static(require('path').resolve('./'))];
// ...
```

...it will works, but I'm wondering why it doesn't with the function declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to invoke your anonymous function:

```
middleware: function (connect) {
  return [proxySnippet, (function () {
    return connect.static(require('path').resolve('./'));
  }())];
```

I wrapped your anonymous function with an optional additional level of parens just to help readability.

Here's an article with more information about self-executing functions: http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/

Comment: That was quite right! Is there any reason to wrap the function between parentheses? I see there is no difference...at least in this case.

Comment: wrapping the function is optional. Some people may prefer the extra parens just because it makes the function look more like a unit, so feel free to skip them if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually calling your anonymous function, while in the "working" version, you are:

```
middleware: function (connect) {
  return [proxySnippet, function () {
    return connect.static(require('path').resolve('./'));
  }()];  // <--- change here
}
```

Now, given that the anonymous wrapper function doesn't really do anything, you should be able to get rid of it:

```
middleware: function (connect) {
  return [proxySnippet, connect.static(require('path').resolve('./'))];
})
```